How to decode compiledInstructions with js- Solana
I am trying to decode the 'compiledInstructions'
How to go from this:
compiledInstructions: [
    {
      programIdIndex: 6,
      accountKeyIndexes: [],
      data: <Buffer 02 f0 49 02 00>
    },
    {
      programIdIndex: 6,
      accountKeyIndexes: [],
      data: <Buffer 03 55 81 f2 07 00 00 00 00>
    },
    {
      programIdIndex: 7,
      accountKeyIndexes: [Array],
      data: <Buffer 52 e1 77 e7 4e 1d 2d 46 cf e5 99 66 00 00 00 00 00 67 04 76 00 00 00 00 d0 ed 77 b5 6d 0b 00 00 00 2d 31 01 00 00 00 00>
    },
    {
      programIdIndex: 12,
      accountKeyIndexes: [Array],
      data: <Buffer 02 00 00 00 c0 e1 e4 00 00 00 00 00>
    }
  ],
  addressTableLookups: [
    {
      accountKey: [PublicKey [PublicKey(4QHABYqrbhcj3EtknQ3dYewAmjuqU9Pstuo7kcCcz3FM)]],
      readonlyIndexes: [Array],
      writableIndexes: [Array]
    }
  ]

to this: solscan
I know there are 4 transactions involved, but only the third one seems to have useful information, I need just the token bought and for how much.
I read the Solana official transactions and instructions docs but found nothing useful.
